# Ganache Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, ganache, error

Trying to connect Ganache **GUI** running on port `7545` to `web3.js`. Getting the below error whenever trying to call any of the functions of web3 -

```
> web3.eth.getBalance("0x907A41F173099E5F5573F0ab43B6Dd9594e3687a").then(console.log);
Promise { <pending> }
> Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/mnt/c/.../web3_development/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:43:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/mnt/c/.../web3_development/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:95:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/mnt/c/.../web3_development/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/mnt/c/Users/.../web3_development/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/mnt/c/.../web3_development/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:349:14)
```

Running `node` on WSL-2.

Any help as to what might be causing the issue or ways to resolve it would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you connecting to the right port?

Comment: @Ismael Think so. 
`let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'));`

Comment: Are you sure ganache is running?

Comment: @Ismael Yes. I can see the accounts with 100 ethers each. Any other way to make sure it is running?

Comment: You can use `curl --data '{"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 127.0.0.1:7545` to check the latest block number.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks. Getting an error message, ` Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7545: Connection refused` This must be it. How do I run ganache so that it starts listening? What I did until now - open Ganache, create a new workspace.

Comment: That should work. Try using other port instead of 7545.

Comment: @Ismael Found that WSL2 cannot connect to `localhost`. Ganache has got the option to change host to WSL. It works now.

Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer. It may help other in similar situation.

Comment: Do you know how we can use Ethernet WSL via the ganache cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came to know that WSL-2 cannot connect to the `localhost` directly. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/2471) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-network-applications).

WSL-2 has its own port to listen to. Ganache gives you the option to select that port instead of `localhost`.

Go to Settings > Server > Hostname > `172.23.160.1 - Ethernet (WSL)`
[image: ganache settings]

Can use the command provided by @Ismael above in the comments to check if the port is connected. It should return the block number. -

`curl --data '{"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 127.0.0.1:7545`